# What is the most number of sets of 8 that N elements can be put into, elements can be reused, but each pair of elements can only be put once

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have N elements, $(E1 ... En)$ . I want to create sets of 8 from these elements. 
Each element can be found in as many sets as possible,
however, each pair of elements must only be found in one set.

For example, after creating  $ (E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8) $ as the first set, I can create  $(E1,E9,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14,E15)$ as the second set, even though E1 is in both the first and second set.

However, I cant create $(E1,E2,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14)$ as the second set as the pair $(E1, E2)$ is already found in the first set.

Then we can add the 3rd, 4th and 5th set and so on until there will come a point where it is not possible to create any more sets.

Is there an algorithm to produce the maximum number of sets of 8 from a initial set of N elements?  What would the maximum number of sets be in that case?

After the generation is complete, let Xi be the number of sets which contain element Ei. What would the minimum value of Xi be for all the elements E1 to En?

Thank you.

Comment: As a rough idea, there are $\frac 12n(n-1)$ pairs of elements.  Each set of $8$ has $28$ pairs, so the best we can hope for is $\frac {n(n-1)}{56}$ subsets

Comment: *social golfer problem*

Comment: Ok thanks i will look it up